# How can I title a plot using the name of the data that the graph comes from?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, title, igraph

I have a list of igraph objects that I am producing plots from (using a forloop) and I would like to give each graph a title that is derived from the object it comes from. Does anyone know how I could do this?

This is my current code:

```
for (i in glst){
 i=delete.vertices(i,which(degree(i)<1))
 plot(i)
 legend(x=-2, y=-0.3, c('nest', 'tree'), pch=21,
     col="#777777", pt.bg= c('orangered3','forestgreen'), pt.cex=2, 
     cex=1, bty="n", ncol=1)
}
```

where glst is a list of igraph objects (called colony12012, colony12013a..... etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to loop over `names(glst)` instead, so `for (i in glst)` becomes `for (name in names(glst))`,

Then `i=delete.vertices(i,which(degree(i)<1))` becomes `i = delete.vertices(glst[[name]], which(degree(glst[[name]]) < 1))`, so you could add `title(main = name)`.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for that!